# Deeplinking in Flutter with GoRouter does not work when using PathUrlStrategy

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-deep-link

In the GoRouter I have defined a path for deeplinking:

```
static const String DEEP_LINK = "deeplink/:someID/:someName";
```

It is working in the browser as expeced using

```
http://localhost:12345/#/deeplink/1/test
```

but when I use

```
setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());
```

to remove the has and enter

```
http://localhost:12345/deeplink/1/test
```

it does not work anymore and I get the error:

```
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/deeplink/1/test"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

What am I doing wrong?